# Python Selenium Multiple element checking

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, while-loop, try-except

I'm using python with selenium to access a webpage. And I want to keep checking rather the element's text exist. Only if it exist then the loop stopped. I come up with some code like:

```
while True:
    try:
        myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 0).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="EP"]/ol/li/li')))
        if(myElem.text == "HELLO"):
            print("Found!")
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Not Found!")
        continue
    break
```

Now, the main issue is instead of 1 element. I need to check 3 elements. If any one of the element was found. Then print the found element and stop the loop. How can I achieved this?

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 0).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="EP"]/ol/li/li')))
WebDriverWait(driver, 0).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="EP"]/div[2]/p[2]/p[2]')))
WebDriverWait(driver, 0).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@class="class20"]')))
```

python: 3.11.1, selenium: 4.8.0

Comment: WebDriverWait can be declared with a X sec limit to check for the element. I would think that if you need to wait for more then X seconds something is wrong with the page or something is wrong with your approach of testing a feature. I usually use 10 second limit. And don't use while true in selenium, because eventually you gonna have an infinite loop.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to do this is to combine the different XPaths into one and check for the existence of "HELLO" in the XPath itself.

```
//*[@id="EP"]/ol/li/li[text()="HELLO"] | //*[@class="class20"][text()="HELLO"] | //*[@id="EP"]/div[2]/p[2]/p[2][text()="HELLO"]
```

If any element is returned, you've found a desired element. You put this in a wait with a reasonable timeout (30s?) and you're done.

```
try:
    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="EP"]/ol/li/li[text()="HELLO"] | //*[@class="class20"][text()="HELLO"] | //*[@id="EP"]/div[2]/p[2]/p[2][text()="HELLO"]')))
    print("Found!")
except TimeoutException:
    print("Not Found!")
```

NOTE: I don't think `//*[@id="EP"]/ol/li/li` and `//*[@id="EP"]/div[2]/p[2]/p[2]` are valid locators. You can't have nested LI or P tags in valid HTML. You might want to check those again and update them.

Answer (score 0):

Put the `try...except...` in a function which takes as parameters the element's xpath and text, and returns True if text is found, otherwise False. Then loop and check if any of the three calls returned True.

```
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException

def check_presence(xpath, txt):
    try:
        myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, 0).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xpath)))
        if myElem.text == txt:
            print("Found!",txt)
            return True
        else:
            print(f'Element exists but text "{txt}" does not match')
    except TimeoutException:
        print("Not Found!",txt)
    return False

while 1:
    a = check_presence('//*[@id="EP"]/ol/li/li'         , "HELLO")
    b = check_presence('//*[@id="EP"]/div[2]/p[2]/p[2]' , "HI")
    c = check_presence('//*[@class="class20"]'          , "CIAO")
    if any([a,b,c]):
        break
```